# IBM Worklight - Adapter procedure response returns "zero results" from Google Places

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, google-places-api, worklight-adapters

I am getting status "ZERO RESULTS" when I invoke HTTP Adapter using Indian latitude and longitude to search for any service like food, malls etc.

Here is my adapter implementation:

```
 function getGooglePlaces(location,name) {

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'maps/api/place/search/json',
        headers: {
            Host: 'maps.googleapis.com'
        },
        parameters : {
            'key'       :   My Key,
            'location'  :  location,
            'radius'    :   '10000',
            'sensor'    :   'false',
            'name'      :  name 
        }
    };

    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); 
    return response;

}
```

}

The JSON response for indian coordinates.
results is the array of places searched

```
{
 "html_attributions": [
  ],
 "isSuccessful": true,
 "responseHeaders": {
  "Alternate-Protocol": "443:quic",
  "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=300",
  "Content-Type": "application\/json; charset=UTF-8",
  "Date": "Wed, 12 Feb 2014 15:06:33 GMT",
  "Expires": "Wed, 12 Feb 2014 15:11:33 GMT",
  "Server": "mafe",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "Vary": "Accept-Language",
  "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
   },
  "responseTime": 609,
  "results": [
   ],
   "status": "ZERO_RESULTS",
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "totalTime": 609
   }
```

Comment: Well, zero_results means that google did not find what you have specified in the radius you have given. When not using adapters, or Worklight at all for this matter, do you find anything in the radius and lat/lon you want?

Comment: Yeah i did it without using worklight and got  some results at same latitude longitude, which i used in worklight adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following and got a valid response, using a Worklight adapter.

- Note that I passed `name` and `location` as part of the parameters object and not like you did (just for the sake of simplification)
- I added a `type` parameter for "restaurant"
- I increased the `radius`

With the above, I got results.
Looks to me like this is a matter of tweaking the request parameters. Nothing related to Worklight adapters here, as it works.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=google+places+returns+zero+results

**GooglePlaces-impl.js**

```
function getPlaces() {
    var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'json',
            path : 'maps/api/place/search/json',
            headers: {
                Host: 'maps.googleapis.com'
            },
            parameters : {
                'key'       : 'make-sure-to-place-here-your-SERVER-KEY-generated-by-Google-GCM-console',
                'location'  : '27.173033, 78.042133',
                'radius'    : '30000',
                'sensor'    : 'false',
                'name'      : 'Taj Mahal',
                'type'      : 'restaurant',
            }
        };

        var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
        return response;
}
```

**Procedure response**

```
{
   "html_attributions": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Alternate-Protocol": "443:quic",
      "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=300",
      "Content-Type": "application\/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Date": "Fri, 14 Mar 2014 05:45:41 GMT",
      "Expires": "Fri, 14 Mar 2014 05:50:41 GMT",
      "Server": "mafe",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "Vary": "Accept-Language",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
   },
   "responseTime": 662,
   "results": [
      {
         "geometry": {
            "location": {
               "lat": 27.175015,
               "lng": 78.042155
            }
         },
         "icon": "http:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/generic_business-71.png",
         "id": "dcc9586b99ab0f0471fccecbe2dbb40fdc1fc2b5",
         "name": "Taj Mahal",
         "photos": [
            {
               "height": 853,
               "html_attributions": [
               ],
               "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAAojrNNKpH2yqjmiph_kNBxiT5DaK_g3N05YtE_mPP5tBrYD8XjyAAz_xEvWAJymfGOeeOTlVgzFUxUeOMQspvoPGogDQyWomDeZsNP7XEW3JsmzmYakDk_vyJBwajiamhluypx6rCDqDCnBWb6JnCLBIQRuBibftSN9xruu2eeZEm5xoUksG5kyFbtZULWpZceNvNhyl72tQ",
               "width": 1280
            }
         ],
         "rating": 4.6,
         "reference": "CnRrAAAA8n6I_Dnlm9UzwTiaTntjcxR-FysL5Ya26Fdcsdb48XOIxiJDGdd3AiK6iUUti41d1BQ1XnBfZoVMKWZ5QOyVZAW8QyH-xqSY8eaQXuxH0atjzXtuaplht-ww76JtbxQLkJ4SUtFrmrs7ZjmZn-_RhBIQmYTB0_yGd_4hm2bHoIKt5xoULaBq-FsZo51jFdxLV377nHM0cCI",
         "types": [
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity": "Agra"
      },
     ...
     ...
     "status": "OK",
       "statusCode": 200,
       "statusReason": "OK",
       "totalTime": 1088
    }
```